# How do I beat Mesmeroth?

Tags: oceanhorn

In Oceanhorn, during the boss sequence with Mesmeroth, I'm able to get him down to his last tiny bit of health, but cannot finish him.

1. I use the shield to reflect his fireballs back at him until he turns into the glowing balls, and hit the balls to reduce his health.
2. I hit the generators to stop the lasers from shooting.
3. Repeat 1-2 until he has a tiny bit of health left, and then he stops turning on the generators.
4. He starts shooting multiple fireballs at once, and I repeatedly reflected his fireballs back at him, but he never loses health or turns into a fireball.

Twice I've done this, and reflected  fireballs for 15 minutes with no progress. I tried bombs, fire spell, ice spell - nothing works. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to defeat Mesmeroth by just re-doing what I'd done before. This time, the health "intervals" that he decreased by were slightly different, and the last time, he went down all the way. I'm think that the situation I was stuck in a few times is actually a bug. There was no need to use arrows or bombs at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use arrows through the fire pot to hit him three times, then 3 balls apear, one of them us the real one, which damages him.

Comment: What do you mean by "arrows through the fire pot"? Whenever I try to shoot him or throw bombs at him, he disappears and reappears elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've defeated shadow mesmeroth several times in the usual way described above, by dodging and disabling the lasers, and by using the shield of chronos to reflect his fireballs back at him, then pummeling the glowing orange ball with the coral saber once he kneels and exposes the ball. This is similar to defeating king angler.

However, it seems maybe an update has changed the game. Twice now only recently I could not defeat him as described. After all his health was depleted (no red visible on the gauge), he seemed to become invulnerable to his own reflected fireballs. I thought it was a bug too. After reading this thread, I tried the arrow through the fire pot and it finished him off.

Smashing clay pots yields only arrows at this time, which I think is a hint to use the bow.

This behavior may vary depending on experience level. I was Vanguard when this happened. Can't say if facing him at a higher or lower level might change this.

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be helpful to shoot arrows at the orbs to identify the correct one -- especially when there's four of them. Other than that, a combination of arrows through the fire and deflection of fire balls seemed to do it.
By the way, some of the vases contained hearts for me when I played it just now.

Answer (score -1):

i also thought it was a bug, I shot an arrow at him though (making the arrow go through the fire pot... it can be a bit difficult to angle, although I was able to do it quickly), and then he died.